# Adding Flex Modules

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, module, flash-builder

Is it possible to add multiple Flex Modules at a time to be built in a project as opposed to adding them one by one, as this is becoming a very tedious task.

This is for both Eclipse and Flash Builder 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add multiple modules through Flash Builder as far as I'm aware. The dialog is only for one-at-a-time.

You can, however, add them yourself via the .actionScriptProperties file located in your project's root folder (you have to browse via explorer to see it).

Under the <modules> node, add as many of the following elements as needed:

```
<module application="src/YourMainApp.mxml" destPath="com/modules/yourModule.swf" optimize="true" sourcePath="com/modules/yourModule.mxml"/>
```

The destPath determines where the module will be located in the published directory structure. The sourcePath is the path within your project to your module's MXML file. Both of these are relative to the main app's location.

Comment: Thank you Adam. I just thought there might be a way to do it through the dialog as it would be much faster to select multiple modules. But alas